# Find all rationals $q$ that make $q+\sqrt{2}$ a reduced quadratic irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question.** Find, with proof, the possible values of a rational number $q$ for which $q+\sqrt{2}$ is a reduced quadratic irrational.

So, by definition a *quadratic irrational* is one of the form $u+v\sqrt{d}$ where $u,v\in\Bbb Q, v\neq 0$ and $d$ being square-free. Then, it is said to be *reduced* if it exceeds $1$ and has conjugate in the interval $(-1, 0)$.

For the question at hand; this corresponds to having $-1<q-\sqrt{2}<0$ and $q+\sqrt{2}>1$.

But I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have $-1 < q-\sqrt{2} < 0$ and $q+\sqrt{2} > 1$, we can simply move the square roots to get the inequalities
$$-1 + \sqrt{2} < q < \sqrt{2} \text{ and } q > 1 - \sqrt{2}$$
Because $-1 + \sqrt{2} > 1 - \sqrt{2}$, our first inequality is all that is necessary. This means we can define a set $S$ of all rational numbers satisfying the inequality as
$$S = \left\{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q \in (-1+\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})\right\}$$
This is the set of all rational numbers between $-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$-1<q-\sqrt{2}<0$ implies that
$$
-1+\sqrt2<q<\sqrt2
$$

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat I dispute that. While my post doesn't give a complete solution (which is not a requirement, by the way; hints are explicitly allowed by the site guidelines), it clearly addresses "where to go from here", which is what is actually asked about. And in what way does my answer post request clarification?